# How to do a not in set comparison in Visual Force formula?

Tags: visualforce, formula

**Question**

Given a value, how can I cleanly compare that it is not equal to a set of values in a visualforce formula?

**Background**

I'm building an email related list component driven by a field set.  To improve the output I'm detecting the display type for some display types, but there are a bunch of other ones that I still just output raw text from.  As I add additional type the rendered tag starts to get nasty, for example

```
rendered="{!field.type <> 'double' && field.type <> 'percent' && field.type <> 'currency'}"
```

Is there a way to do this without having to repeat field.type so much?  Hypothetically it could be something like this:

```
rendered="{!NOT(('percent','double','currency') = field.type}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{!NOT(REGEX(field.type,'percent|double|currency'))}
```

Answer (score 2):

try CONTAINS

```
rendered="{!!CONTAINS('percent double currency', field.type)}"
```